# Spring security JWT

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

I am trying to implement JWT based auth with Spring security.

Currently, using the below dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.7</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.7</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

**JWtUtil class**

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;

@Component
public class JWTUtil implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Value("${springbootwebfluxjjwt.jjwt.secret}")
    private String secret;

    @Value("${springbootwebfluxjjwt.jjwt.expiration}")
    private String expirationTime;

    public Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secret.getBytes())).parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
        return getAllClaimsFromToken(token).getSubject();
    }

    public Date getExpirationDateFromToken(String token) {
        return getAllClaimsFromToken(token).getExpiration();
    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        final Date expiration = getExpirationDateFromToken(token);
        return expiration.before(new Date());
    }

    public String generateToken(User user) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        claims.put("role", user.getRoles());
        return doGenerateToken(claims, user.getUsername());
    }

    private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String username) {
        Long expirationTimeLong = Long.parseLong(expirationTime); // in second

        final Date createdDate = new Date();
        final Date expirationDate = new Date(createdDate.getTime() + expirationTimeLong * 1000);

        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(username).setIssuedAt(createdDate)
                .setExpiration(expirationDate)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secret.getBytes())).compact();
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token) {
        return !isTokenExpired(token);
    }
}
```

Came across spring dependency for JWT. But unable to find the correponding API.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there any example to convert the current JWTUtil with the spring-security-jwt API's?

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Java code for this:

```
//decode using token as String
Jwt decodedJwt = JwtHelper.decode(jwtToken);
//get Claims
JSONObject claims = new JSONObject(decodedJwt.getClaims());
//get expiration date
Date exp = new Date(claims.getLong("exp"));
//get subject
claims.getString("sub");
```

Additional you can check [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.springframework.security.jwt.JwtHelper) some examples for `org.springframework.security.jwt.JwtHelper`

EDIT:
in version `1.1.0.RELEASE` `JwtHelper` is `deprecated` and you can use [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using spring security with jwt and the dependecy I have is this one :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I want to go with spring jwt dependency. Can you post the java code as well for this?

Comment: here it is : https://github.com/mohamedYoussfi/spring-security-jwt-micro-service/tree/master/src/main/java/org/sid/sec , if you speak french you can find his  tutorial on youtube he explained everything about spring security and jwt